# Why are NEC and ABYC ampacity ratings different?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I believe that the NEC code says that a single un-bundled conductor of 4/0 75C copper wire has an ampacity of 230A. I am doing some work on an RV and the general consensus is that the American Boat and Yacht Council standards are more applicable than the NEC standards for this use case. ABYC E-11 (https://boathowto.com/wiresize/wiresize_tables_abyc.pdf) says that the amapcity of 4/0 75C wire is 360A.

Why are the ratings so different?

Comment: "**an** RV" 230A to 360A? A single RV is routinely 50A and might be closer to 100A like a small house. But why 200A or more? In any case, aluminum is going to be a much better deal, cost-wise, than copper at anything close to those sizes.

Comment: An RV is typically 50A @ 120V, I am looking to be able to pull 300A @ 12V from the battery bank. The distance on the wire runs is like 5' to combine the batteries in parallel and to go from the batteries to an inverter and bus bar/fuse block after which the current is much more reasonable.

Comment: DC is different from AC and low voltage different from high (not super-high, in this case 120V/240V - the standard RV 50A is actually at 240V). So the NEC codes **simply do not apply here**. Once you get through the inverter then it is essentially NEC territory.

Comment: The Blue Sea ampacity chart (https://www.bluesea.com/resources/1437) is not directly applicable necessarily, but is produced by a major boating equipment supplier.

Comment: @JonCuster that chart is based on ABCY E-11.

Comment: @StrongBad - yes, although it only goes up to 200A. It is nice in so far as having voltage drops vs distance in it. If your RV/boat circuits are less than X feet long you often can use a smaller gauge than might be suggested by length-insensitive codes.

Comment: Make sure you read NEC 551.1 to know when NEC applies to RVs.

Answer (score 5):

> I believe that the NEC code says that a single un-bundled conductor of 4/0 75C copper wire has an ampacity of 230A.

The NEC *never* deals with single conductors for AC power (for all practical purposes).

This is because it is critical that all current-carrying conductors of an AC circuit be physically together, lest they form a transformer and induce damaging vibration and heating.

If you look closely at an NEC table, it should say “applies to bundles of up to three current-carrying conductors in the same cable, conduit, or raceway” (or similar).

Circuit grouping of DC conductors is not mandatory because the magnetic effects are not significant - current flows start and stop far too slowly/rarely to worry about (compared to 50/60Hz AC).

Thus the baseline for the ABYC charts is individual (non-bundled/grouped) wires - because you can do that.

If you calculate the ABYC derate for two conductors in a cable, it will be almost the same as the NEC number.